# C include file extension

Tags: c, include

I've always seen the C include extension as .h.

I am working on a project with include extensions of .r.  I believe the extension .r refers to Mac resource forks.

I'm wondering if C allows the extension on an include file to be anything?

The code compiles without any errors.

examples:

```
#include "HostTypes.h" 
#include "IdentifySpec.r"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no restriction on the name (including extension) of an include file.
All of the following are valid

```
#include "foo.bar"
#include "look_ma_no_extension"
#include "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9"
```

However, using .h is preferred because it is the usual extension :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this without worries. The C preprocessor includes whatever you tell it to include.

Answer (score 0):

If it compile and it works, it's ok ;) *.h* is just a convention